# Integral by substitution STEP

Tags: integration

In a STEP question we first proved that if $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{u f(u)} \, du = F(u) +c$ than by letting $u=x^m \Rightarrow du = mx^{m-1} dx$

$\displaystyle\therefore \int \frac{mx^{m-1}}{x^m f(x^m)} \, dx = F(x^m) + c \iff \int \frac{m}{x f(x^m)} \, dx = F(x^m) + c$

Then we are asked to evaluate $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x^n - x} \, dx = \int\frac{1}{x(x^{n-1}-1)} \, dx$

In the answer it says:

### by considering

$$\frac{1}{u(u-1)} \, du= \int \frac{1}{u-1} - \frac{1}{u} \, du \ 
= \ln |u-1| - \ln |u| + c \ 
= \ln \left| \frac{u-1}{u} \right| + c $$

Then, by the first result: $\displaystyle\int \frac{1}{x^n - x} \, dx = \frac{1}{n-1} \ln \left| \frac{x^{n-1} - 1}{x^{n-1}} \right| + c = \boxed{\ln \left| \frac{\sqrt[n-1]{x^{n-1}-1}}{x} \right| + c}$

Could someone explain this to me?
What should be $u$ and $f(u)$ and how do we arrive at the answer?

Comment: You couldn't take out the br-s? Liar. Edit your answer and make it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setting $x^{n-1}=u$ gives you $du=(n-1)x^{n-2}dx$, one has
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{1}{x(x^{n-1}-1)}dx&=\frac{1}{n-1}\int\frac{du}{u(u-1)}\\&=\frac{1}{n-1}\int\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac 1u\right)du\\&=\frac{1}{n-1}\ln\left|\frac{u-1}{u}\right|+C\end{align}$$